# Building library with make

Tags: makefile

I have makefile with the following content:

```
libcommon.a : $(COMMON_CFILES:.c=.o) filter_scan.o filter_expr.o $(META_O_FILES)
        ar rcv $@ $^
```

So I have a few small questions about  this syntax.

1. What are .a .so .o extenstions?
2. What does mean
   $(COMMON_CFILES:.c=.o)

specifically, what are .c and .o?

(there is a COMMON_CFILES "label", (i don't know how to name that) with the list of .c files)

3. What is ar rcv $@ $^?

Comment: It's better to suggest an edit, than blindly downvoting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.a` is a static library. They are maintained with the `ar` command.

`.so` is a shared library.

`$(COMMON_CFILES:.c=.o)` takes a Makefile macro named COMMON_CFILES, splits it into words, and replaces `.c` with `.o` in each token. So it converts C source file names to their corresponding object file names.

`.c` is the suffix of C source files.

`ar rcv $@ $^` updates the archive libcommon.a (`$@`) with the files from its dependencies. (`$^`)

Comment: ok, thanks. I've got the whole picture, now it's time to read mans.

Comment: Technically, `$(COMMON_CFILES:.c=.o)` only operates on the **end** of each word. It is equivalent to `$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(COMMON_CFILES))`. See section [`6.3.1 Substitution References`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) of the manual.